# Cross Origin error on ajax OAuth authentication

Tags: ajax, oauth, cross-domain, microservices

I'm working on a web project using microservices. When I try to access the OAuth access token from the Authentication server through an ajax call, I get an error in the browser console like this:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:8080/oauth/token' from origin 'http://localhost:8090' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

My Ajax

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'localhost:8080/oauth/token',
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Authorization": "Basic " + auth_token
  },
  data: {
    "username": "user",
    "password": "123",
    "grant_type": "password"
  },
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data)
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(textStatus);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I tried looking up in previous stackoverflow questions and found this similar question. But the answer doesn't work for me as I'm not loading a local file. I'm loading the model from Tomcat.
I'm just a beginner in microservices and rest api in general. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your URL isn't a URL, it doesn't have a scheme. Try with `http://` or `https://` on the front as appropriate.

Comment: @peeebeee Tried that. Now the error is : Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/oauth/token' from origin 'http://localhost:8090' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status

Comment: OK, then the service running at port 8080 needs to provide CORS headers and respond to OPTIONS requests for the pre-flight request.